# How to extract a single road from OSM GIS Database?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, export, road

Is there a way to extract a single row out of the OSM-GIS-Database (by a Query)?
It would be so much easier if I could find an EER Model of the Database.

I was searching a long term and found very less information about that. So I think it would be the best to ask the pros before thinking it's impossible.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Did you load the OSM data to a Postgresql/PostGIS database?

Comment: Yes I exactly did this. I also use these data as a base for a tile service

Comment: Which importing tool did you use?

Comment: OSM2PSQL Was used for importing

Comment: OSM2PSQL we used for importing. It created a Database with about 9 Tables (geometry_columns, planet_osm_line, planet_osm_nodes, planet_osm_point, planet_osm_polygon, planet_osm_rels, planet_osm_roads, planet_osm_ways, spatial_ref_sys)

Answer (score 1):

The basic format is the same as any SQL query: `select [fields] from [table] where [query]`

Here's an example from the [osm2pgsql schema](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql/schema) page: `select name, place, ST_XMin(way), ST_YMin(way) from planet_osm_point where place='city' order by name`    The schema page should also help you understand the different tables.

But maybe there's something more complicated you're trying to do?  If so, please expand on your question.

Comment: That didn't helped me because i need a full road to overlay it on a map (for interactive functionality)

Comment: So that should be in planet_osm_line or planet_osm_roads.  Can you get the road by osm ID, or by using the tags (like name or ref)?  Or are you wanting to use a spatial query?